# How to deregister / unregister Firebase user when registered using Phone Auth

Tags: objective-c, firebase, firebase-authentication

I have registered users using Firebase convenience FUIPhoneAuth. When I try to delete the user with:

```
[user deleteWithCompletion:^(NSError * _Nullable error) ..
```

*I get an error message saying the only recently authenticate users can be deleted.*

```
"This operation is sensitive and requires recent authentication. Log in again before retrying this request."
```

---

In order to deregister the user, I first need to re-authenticate the user which requires a FIRAuthCredential "credential" parameter:

```
[user reauthenticateWithCredential:credential completion:^(NSError *_Nullable error) {
```

Firebase doc mentions that one should save FIRAuthCredential when a delegate gets called.(store it in NSUserDefaults)

```
[[FIRPhoneAuthProvider provider] verifyPhoneNumber:userInput
                                    UIDelegate:nil
                                    completion:^(NSString * _Nullable verificationID, NSError * _Nullable error) {
```

I have used FUIPhoneAuth with signInWithPresentingViewController: and did not receive a FIRAuthCredential upon registration. 
I am thinking that if I can get hold of the "FIRAuthCredential" I can re-use it
to deregister the user. But when using the *FUIPhoneAuth* this does not seem possible.
*How do I get hold of the *FIRAuthCredential* in order to deregister a user?*

1. ***Can one reuse the "FIRAuthCredential* or does one need to do a complete re-authentication with a SMS before the user can be
   deleted?**
2. **How does one deregister a user when registered using *FUIPhoneAuth*?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Re-Authenticate as per normal and then call deleteWithCompletion.
Since you already have the cell number, you do not need to recapture that.

```
FIRAuth *auth = [(AppDelegate*)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate auth];
FIRPhoneAuthProvider *provider = [FIRPhoneAuthProvider providerWithAuth:auth];

[provider verifyPhoneNumber:user.phoneNumber
                 UIDelegate:nil
                 completion:^(NSString * _Nullable verificationID, NSError * _Nullable error) {
                        if (error) {
                            return;
                        }

                        UIAlertController *alert = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"Verification"
                                                                                       message:@"Enter the SMS verfication code" preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];

                        [alert addTextFieldWithConfigurationHandler:^(UITextField *textField) {
                            textField.placeholder = @"SMS Code";
                            textField.clearButtonMode = UITextFieldViewModeWhileEditing;
                            textField.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect;
                        }];

                        UIAlertAction *defaultAction = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"OK"
                                                                                style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                                                                              handler:^(UIAlertAction * action) {

                                                                                  NSArray *textfields = alert.textFields;
                                                                                  UITextField *codeField = textfields[0];

                                                                                  FIRAuthCredential *credential = [provider credentialWithVerificationID:verificationID verificationCode:codeField.text];

                                                                                  [user reauthenticateWithCredential:credential completion:^(NSError * _Nullable error) {
                                                                                      // unregister
                                                                                      [user deleteWithCompletion:^(NSError * _Nullable error) {
                                                                                          if (error) {
                                                                                              NSLog(@"FIR: User delete failed: %@",error.localizedDescription);

                                                                                          }
                                                                                          NSLog(@"FIR: User Deleted success");
                                                                                      }];
                                                                                  }];
                                                                              }];

                        UIAlertAction *cancelAction = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Cancel" style:UIAlertActionStyleCancel handler: ^(UIAlertAction * action) {
                        }];

                        [alert addAction:defaultAction];
                        [alert addAction:cancelAction];
                        [self presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil];

                    }];
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure where the docs mention saving the credential in `NSUserDefaults`, but generally you shouldn't store sensitive information there. If you must for some reason, it should be in keychain.

You must understand that *authentication* and *verification* are two very different things. Authentication occurs every time you sign into the app (generating the credentials/tokens, etc...). Verification, on the other hand, is optional and in most cases, should occur just once (per verification method) in a user's in-app lifetime.

For instance, when you register as a Facebook user, you verify your email only once, you may also verify your phone number with SMS just once, but you get authenticated each and every time you log in.

**First Answer:**
So, to answer your first question, what you need in order to delete a user is re-authentication, which is completely independent of verification. You may relate this to Facebook asking for your password (even though you're logged in) before deactivating your account or attempting any big changes.

**Second Answer:**
As of your second question, getting the users' credentials depends on what *type* of credential it is (do you use email/password? Google/Facebook/Twitter?). Each method has its own way of "recreating" the credential, so to speak.

[Email/Password](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/ios/firebaseauth/api/reference/Classes/FIREmailPasswordAuthProvider)

```
FIRAuthCredential *credential = [FIREmailPasswordAuthProvider credentialWithEmail: email password: password];
```

[Facebook](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/ios/firebaseauth/api/reference/Classes/FIRFacebookAuthProvider)

```
FIRAuthCredential *credential = [FIRFacebookAuthProvider credentialWithAccessToken: fbTokenString];
```

[Google](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/ios/firebaseauth/api/reference/Classes/FIRGoogleAuthProvider)

```
FIRAuthCredential *credential = [FIRGoogleAuthProvider credentialWithIDToken: token accessToken: accessToken];
```

[Twitter](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/ios/firebaseauth/api/reference/Classes/FIRTwitterAuthProvider)

```
FIRAuthCredential *credential = [FIRTwitterAuthProvider credentialWithToken: session.authToken secret: session.authTokenSecret];
```

My answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41720046/3551916) might be helpful in terms of prompting the user to re-enter the password in case you're using email/password credentials.

You can use the newly generated credentials to re-authenticate as you did in your post (here's the [relevant documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/manage-users#re-authenticate_a_user)), then you can use `deleteWithCompletion` in the re-authentication completion-block.

**Update**

The link you provided states that you should store the "verification ID" in `NSUserDefaults`, not the auth credential. The verification ID and verification code (what's sent in the SMS) pair are used together to get auth credentials and then sign in. You don't *have* to store it, they just recommend that you do in case the app restarts upon switching to and from the Messages app. You can safely delete the verification ID after the user signs in.

As of your second comment, you can get the auth credentials by relaunching the verification process (this [part](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/phone-auth#sign-in-the-user-with-the-verification-code) of the link you mentioned; send an SMS, get the user input, then call `credentialWithVerificationID`). You should **not** save the credential locally as it's a security risk and it expires anyway. Only save the verification ID temporarily until the user enters the verification code and gets authenticated.

Comment: The Firebase docs that mentions NSUserDefaults is located here:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/phone-auth?authuser=0
Search for: "Save the verification ID and restore it when your app loads."

Comment: What about "FIRPhoneAuthProviderID", this is the only one I am using?

Comment: Updated my answer!

Answer (score 0):

Please do not store credentials on the device. You are misreading the docs. It requires re-authentication for a reason. Storing a credential beats the point of that. You should simply reauthenticate the user to delete them. This is similar to asking an email/password user to provide their current password again before deleting their account, updating their password, updating email, updating shipping address, credit card info, etc.

Besides, even if you store these phone credentials:

- they will expire in a few minutes as they are short lived.
- they are only usable once so holding on to them is useless after sign-in.