# Android FirebaseUI Auth - How to reauthenticate?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebaseui

Related Question: [How does Firebase Auth UI deal with reauthentication?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41712370/how-does-firebase-auth-ui-deal-with-reauthentication)
(This question is for iOS, and is unsolved)

I would like to allow a user to update their email/password/etc with FirebaseUI on Android.

According to the [guide](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/firebaseui), the "drop-in" UI provides:

> **Account Management** - flows to handle account management tasks, such as account creation and password resets.

On [GitHub](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/blob/master/auth/README.md), it looks like the AuthUI Management Page feature is still in progress (right?)

So, I've created my own account management page, but some of the actions are security sensitive and require [reauthentication](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/manage-users):

> Some security-sensitive actions—such as deleting an account, setting a primary email address, and changing a password—require that the user has recently signed in. If you perform one of these actions, and the user signed in too long ago, the action fails and throws `FirebaseAuthRecentLoginRequiredException`.

The example code requires that we retrieve the credentials from the user before passing it to the reauthenticate:

```
FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();

// Get auth credentials from the user for re-authentication. The example below shows
// email and password credentials but there are multiple possible providers,
// such as GoogleAuthProvider or FacebookAuthProvider.
AuthCredential credential = EmailAuthProvider
        .getCredential("user@example.com", "password1234");

// Prompt the user to re-provide their sign-in credentials
user.reauthenticate(credential)
        .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                Log.d(TAG, "User re-authenticated.");
            }
        });
```

However, getting the credentials from the user is non-trivial, since I allow sign in with Google, email, facebook, and phone number.  For example, signing in with a phone number requires that a text be sent to the phone.  This needs more than just an alert dialog asking for a password.

On Github, there was a merge for [adding a reauthentication builder](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/pull/583) a few months ago, but I've been unable to find this function in the most recent FirebaseUI version.  Something like `AuthUI.createReauthIntentBuilder()` would be perfect.

**What is the best approach for re-authenticating a user with Firebase on Android?**  Can I use the `AuthUI.createSignInIntent()`, or is implementing my own reauthentication dialog really the only way?

Currently using: FirebaseUI Auth 3.1.2

Comment: FirebaseUI re-authentication is not yet supported. Please file a request for this feature in the GitHub repo. You can also file an official request on https://firebase.google.com/support/

Answer (score -2):

```
mUser.updateEmail(cek_email).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
       if (task.isSuccessful()){
          Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "succes", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

       }
    }
});
```

use method `updateEmail`

Comment: Hi Renal. Please don't post code only answers. You need to add an explanation. [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: first u must get currentUser from firebase user and then use updateEmail method which has been provided by firebase

Comment: This isn't what OP asked for at all. Please look at the question before posting.